# Generic composable Ecto query w/ dynamic field name in query expression

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm trying to allow for passing in a field name and running it in an Ecto query expression dynamically, like so:

```
def count_distinct(query, field_name) when is_binary(field_name) do
  query
  |> select([x], count(Map.fetch!(x, field_name), :distinct))
end
```

However, I get this compilation error:

```
(Ecto.Query.CompileError) `Map.fetch!(x, field_name)` is not a valid query expression
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to use [field/2](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.API.html#field/2) to dynamically generate fields in queries:

```
query
|> select([x], count(field(x, ^field_name), :distinct))
```

An example using the other query syntax for completion:

```
from x in query,
  select: count(field(x, ^field_name), :distinct)
```

Comment: Was so close! Thank you! :D

Comment: Is this possible without using atoms, but rather a normal string? It seems like a bad idea to convert every potential dynamic field into an atom which cannot be garbage collected AFAIK.

Comment: @Tarlen You can use `to_existing_atom` if you need to convert a string to an atom from user input. Using an atom is fine because the if the field exists in the schema, the atom will already exist.

Comment: Problem is that I let users add their own fields to a model, so I cannot know them at design time

Comment: Which database are you using? If the field function doesn't work for you, consider a fragment.

Comment: @Tarlen When you have dynamic user inputs you shouldn't convert them to an atom. The number of atoms is bounded and the VM can crash.