# Ecto: How to dynamically provide field name and value to where clauses?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I try to create function to dynamically add filters to Ecto query.
Before adding where clause I add joins to the query, so I use bindings.
What I try looks like this:

```
def param_to_where(query, field_name, value) do
  query |> where([_a, ..., b], b.field_name == value)
end
```

But the result query tries to match the value against "field_name" column which doesn't exist. How to provide dynamic arguments "field_name" and "value" to the query?

I tried like this:

```
def param_to_where(query, field_name, value) do
  query |> where([_a, ..., b], b[field_name] == value)
end
```

this:

```
def param_to_where(query, field_name, value) do
  query |> where([_a, ..., b], b.^field_name == value)
end
```

this:

```
def param_to_where(query, field_name, value) do
  query |> where([_a, ..., b], b[^field_name] == value)
end
```

Nothing worked.
the static query works as expected:

```
  query |> where([_a, ..., b], b.name = "John")
```

Comment: Use `field(b, ^field_name) == ^value`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/34641687.

Comment: Thanks, Dogbert, it worked! Please, make it an answer. I couldn't google that answer, sorry.

Comment: I've marked it as a duplicate since Gazler has already answered exactly the same thing. :)

Comment: and if I wanted to provide dynamically the ecto function to the query?def param_to_where(query, field_name, value, operation) do
  query |> where([_a, ..., b], field(b, ^field_name)  ^operation(^value))
end ; could I have written like this?

Comment: What do you mean by "provide dynamically the ecto function"?

Comment: look at my previous comment, I changed it.

Comment: I mean functions kind of ilike, between...

Comment: I don't think that's possible for arbitrary input at runtime. If there were a limited set of such inputs possible, I'd create a `case` and return a different `where` from each, e.g. `case operation do :like -> where(..., like(field(...), ^value)); :ilike -> ... end`.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I've made a function clause for each operation I needed, everything works!